# A formula for the radical of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

> Let I be an ideal in A. Then r(I)= { $x\in A | x^n \in I$ for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$}.
> $\phi : A \to A/I$ is the natural map. Then  prove that $r(I) = \phi^{-1} (N_{A/I})$. N is nilradical there.

I am reading from notes in commutative algebra. $N_{A/I}$ means set of all x in A/I such that $x^n\subseteq I$ for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$ but how it's inverse image   will be equal to  r(I)?

Can you please tell?

Edit : Assuming the above result to be true I was asked to Find the r(I) in following cases.

(i) $\mathbb{Z}$  and $I= 9\mathbb{Z}$

(ii) $\mathbb{Z}$ and $I= 12\mathbb{Z}$.

Nil Radical in (i) is {0,3,6} and Nil Radical in (ii) is {0,6}.

but I am unable to understand how to find inverse image of such a set ie how to find inverse image of  $\phi^{-1} $({0,3,6}) and $\phi^{-1}$( {0,6})?

Please help.

Comment: Can the downvoter please explain why he /she is downvoting?

Answer (score 1):

**Question:** "Let $I$ be an ideal in $A$. Then $r(I)= { x∈A|x^n∈I \text{ for some }n∈N}$. Let $ϕ:A→A/I$ is the natural map. Then prove that $r(I)=ϕ^{−1}(N_{A/I})$. $N$ is nilradical there."

**Answer:** Let $p: A\rightarrow A/I:=B$ and let $N:=nil(B)$ be the nilradical of $B$. Let $J:=p^{-1}(N)$ be the inverse image ideal of $N$.

**Claim:** there is an equality of ideals $J =r(I)$.

Assume $x\in J$. It follows $p(x)\in N$ hence $p(x)^n=p(x^n)=0$ in $B$. This implies $x^n\in I$ and hence $x\in r(I)$ and $J \subseteq r(I)$. Assume $x\in r(I)$. It follows $x^n\in I$ and $p(x)^n=p(x^n)=0$ hence $p(x)\in N$ and $x\in J$.

If $I=(3^2) \subseteq R:=\mathbb{Z}$ it follows $(3)\subseteq R/(3^2)$ is the only prime ideal hence $rad(R/(3^2))=(3)$. If $J:=(12)=(3)(2^2)$ it follows from the chinese remainder lemma that

$$R/J \cong R/(3)\oplus R/(2^2)$$

and the prime ideals are $J_1:=(3)\oplus R/(2^2)$ and $J_2:=R/(3)\oplus (2)$ hence the radical is

$$rad(R/J)=J_1 \cap J_2=J_1J_2=(6)$$

since the intersection of coprime ideals equals the product. In general if $n:=\prod_{i=1}^n p_i^{r_i} \in R$ is any postitive integer with $p_i$ distinct primes, it follows the radical satisfies

$$rad(R/(n))=(p_1\cdots p_n).$$

Comment: Kindly also consider question asked in edit of the question.

Comment: Why (3) is the only prime ideal? Can you please explain?

Comment: @Avenger Given a product of commutative rings $A\times B$, its  prime ideals are precisely ideals of the form $P\times B$ for $P$ a prime ideal of $A$, and $A\times Q$ for $Q$ a prime ideal of $B$.  Thus for $\mathbb{Z}/(12)\cong \mathbb{Z}/(3)\times \mathbb{Z}/(4)$, we may list its prime ideals by listing the prime ideals of $\mathbb{Z}/(3)$ and $\mathbb{Z}/(4)$.  In the former case $0=(3)$ is the only ideal.  In the latter case $2\cdot 2=0$, so any prime ideal must contain $(2)$, hence must be $(2)$.  Thus we get one apiece: $J_1$ and $J_2$.

Comment: @Avenger It should be clear why ideals of the above forms $A\times Q$ and $P\times B$ are prime: e.g. if $(x,y)(z,w)\in  A\times Q$ then $yw\in Q$ so $y\in Q$ or $w\in Q$, so $(x,y)\in A\times Q$ or $(z,w)\in A\times Q$.

Comment: @Avenger Conversely, any prime ideal of $A\times B$ contains $(0,0)=(1,0)(0,1)$ so contains $A\times 0$ or $0\times B$.  Thus the prime ideal must have the form $A\times I$ or $J\times B$, for ideals $I\subset B$ or $J\subset A$ which must be prime.

Comment: @tkf Thank you very much! Can you also tell how $J_1 \cap J_2 =(6)$? I am not able to understand how $ R/(2)^2 \cap (2) =(2) $. I think it should be $(2)^2)$ not (2).

Comment: $J_1$ is the ideal of $\mathbb{Z}/(12)$ consisting of all numbers which map into $0\times \mathbb{Z}/(4)$ under the isomorphism $$\mathbb{Z}/(12)\cong\mathbb{Z}/(3)\times\mathbb{Z}/(4).$$  That is $J_1=(3)\subset \mathbb{Z}/(12)$.  Similarly $J_2=(2)\subset \mathbb{Z}/(12)$.  A number is divisible by both $2$ and $3$ if and only if it is divisible by $6$.

Comment: If you intersect a ring with the set of elements in it divisible by $2$, then you get the set of elements divisible by $2$ - this is essentially a tautology.

Comment: @tkf I am really sorry but I am still not able to understand how you $J_2 =2$,maybe  because  I don't understand how you wrote that $J_1$ is the ideal of $\mathbb{Z} /(12)$ consisting of all numbers which map into $0\times \mathbb{Z}/(4)$

Comment: @tkf Can you please elaborate on this?

Comment: So we have the natural quotient map $\mathbb{Z}/(12)\to \mathbb{Z}/(4)$, that sends $x\mod 12 \mapsto x \mod 4$.  If $x=2y+12t$ then $x=2(y+6t)$, so any element of $(2)\subset \mathbb{Z}/(12)$ maps to $(2)\subset \mathbb{Z}/(4)$.  Conversely if $x=2y+1+12t$ then $x=2(y+6t)+1$, so if $x\notin(2)\subset \mathbb{Z}/(12)$, then  $x\notin(2)\subset \mathbb{Z}/(4)$.